# Как вставить с задержкой в HTML контейнер с сообщением

Tags: javascript

В общем проблема в следующем не работает задержка вывода.
Не могу понять почему?

```js
const demand=[{mes1:`<p>я</p>`},{mes2:`<p>люблю</p>`},{mes3:`<p>JS</p>`}];

const container = document.querySelector('.container');


const addTemplate = (template) => {
         container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `${template}`)
};



for (let item = 0; item < demand.length; item++) {
let deley=0;

    for (let key in demand[item]) {
        setTimeout(()=>{addTemplate(demand[item][key])},deley);
        deley+=5000;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотри коммент

```js
const demand=[{mes1:`<p>я</p>`},{mes2:`<p>люблю</p>`},{mes3:`<p>JS</p>`}];

const container = document.querySelector('.container');


const addTemplate = (template) => {
         container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `${template}`)
};


let deley=0;
for (let item = 0; item < demand.length; item++) {
// let deley=0; ERROR - все время обнуляется

    for (let key in demand[item]) {
        setTimeout(()=>{addTemplate(demand[item][key])},deley);
        deley+=5000;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
</div>
```